# Jetpack compose ViewModel architecture when working with maps

Tags: android, google-maps, architecture, android-jetpack-compose, mapbox-android

I'm still trying to wrap up my head about how to architecture apps with jetpack compose, and I've run into a use case that I'm not sure what should be the "correct" approach.

So this is the scenario:

You have a screen with a map, and you press the "My location" button (you know, the one that centers the map on the user current location). An event is triggered from the UI and handled on the ViewModel, so the ViewModel gets the current location and updates the data (you can call it State, I've been experimenting with having States and something similar that are handled as single events), which calls all the UI functions again and updates the view to center the map. Then, the user moves the app again, and presses the "My Location" button. The map is not centered correctly, but the State is the same ( assuming the user didn't move).

How should this be structured?
I'm guessing the secret is all related to where you hoist which states, the viewmodel and all that, but I still can't quite figure it out.

Currently, I'm passing down a ViewModel to a composable which holds only the map view. There I have a variable that holds a location, that is updated when the ViewModel receives a new event ( the user clicking the button ). This is working, but when I had the same logic on the parent composable it wasn't and it is not clear to me why.

Some code so it's not all talk:

```
    @Composable
            fun Map(
                mapViewModel: MapViewModel
            ){
        
               var mapLocation: MapLocation? = null
               val event: MapViewEvent? = mapViewModel.viewEvents.collectAsState(initial = null).value
               when (event) {
                is MapViewEvent.MyLocation -> mapLocation = event.myLocation
                null -> {mapLocation = null}
               }

            //Android view that holds the map
            AndroidView(
               factory = {
                  //map init
               },
               update = {
                  if (mapLocation != null) {
                     moveMapToLocation(mapLocation)
               }
               NoOpUpdate
               })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`mapLocation` and `event` are not compose states, so compose cannot detect their changes.

```
var mapLocation by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
val event: MapViewEvent? by mapViewModel.viewEvents.collectAsState(initial = null)
```

Comment: but it is detecting, the code is working as it is right now, but I think I should not pass the viewmodel to this component. I would like to pass down only the `mapLocation`to this component, but when I do that the change is not detected